# No Data Received - server sent no data - ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a query that when I place certain restrictions, or run directly from phpmyadmin works perfectly.....but when I run it from my php code it gives me a blank page and error - ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.  I do know the error happens on this line of code:

```
$export = mysql_query ( $select ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );
```

It is almost as if the query is timing out, but I've tried changing the variables in php.ini to not allow it to time out.  The query that works on the back end but not in the file is this:

```
    SELECT  `tbl_entry`.`entry_id` ,  `tbl_entry_item`.`entry_item_id` , 
CASE WHEN  `tbl_entry`.`in_out_type` =  'I'
THEN  'Inbound'
ELSE  'Shipped Out'
END AS  'Status',  `tbl_customer`.`customer_name` ,  `tbl_serv_prov`.`name` AS  'Carrier_name',  `tbl_origin_dest`.`name` AS  'Origin', destination.`name` AS  'Destination', `tbl_project`.`project_name` ,  `tbl_component`.`component_name` , 
CASE WHEN  `tbl_entry`.`truck_arrive` <  '1999-01-01 00:00:00'
THEN  '0'
ELSE  `tbl_entry`.`truck_arrive` 
END AS  'truck_arrive', 
CASE WHEN  `tbl_entry`.`offload_begin` <  '1999-01-01 00:00:00'
THEN  '0'
ELSE  `tbl_entry`.`offload_begin` 
END AS  'offload_begin', 
CASE WHEN  `tbl_entry`.`offload_end` <  '1999-01-01 00:00:00'
THEN  '0'
ELSE  `tbl_entry`.`offload_end` 
END AS  'offload_end', 
CASE WHEN  `tbl_entry`.`truck_left_site` <  '1999-01-01 00:00:00'
THEN  '0'
ELSE  `tbl_entry`.`truck_left_site` 
END AS  'truck_left_site',  `tbl_entry`.`pro_number` ,  `tbl_entry`.`checklist` ,  `tbl_entry`.`truck_rail_barge` ,  `tbl_entry`.`bol` ,  `tbl_entry`.`log_mode` ,  `tbl_entry_item`.`damage` , `tbl_entry_item`.`serial_number` ,  `tbl_entry_item`.`dmg_desc` , ds.`status_name` AS  'Damage_Type',  `tbl_entry_item`.`fix_before_ship` , fs.`status_name` AS  'Fix_status', `tbl_entry_item`.`mpp_defect` ,  `tbl_entry_item`.`incident` ,  `tbl_entry_item`.`defect_avoided` ,  `tbl_entry_item`.`damage_source` ,  `tbl_entry_item`.`defect` , `tbl_entry_item`.`defect_comments` ,  `tbl_entry_item`.`incident_escalation` ,  `tbl_entry_item`.`incident_injury` ,  `tbl_entry_item`.`incident_report_link` , `tbl_entry_item`.`in_out_type` ,  `tbl_entry_item`.`outbound_entry_id` ,  `tbl_entry_item`.`outbound_entry_item_id` ,  `tbl_entry_item`.`incident_esc_sent` , `tbl_entry_item`.`defect_comment` ,  `tbl_entry_item`.`mpp_reason` ,  `tbl_entry_item`.`claim_check` ,  `tbl_entry_item`.`set_number` ,  `tbl_entry_item`.`customer_tag` , `tbl_entry_item`.`pad_number` ,  `tbl_eq`.equip_name, tbl_entry.on_site_status
FROM tbl_entry
LEFT JOIN tbl_entry_item ON  `tbl_entry`.`entry_id` =  `tbl_entry_item`.`entry_id` 
LEFT JOIN tbl_customer ON  `tbl_entry`.`customer_id` =  `tbl_customer`.`customer_id` 
LEFT JOIN tbl_serv_prov ON  `tbl_entry`.`serv_prov_id` =  `tbl_serv_prov`.`serv_prov_id` 
LEFT JOIN tbl_origin_dest ON  `tbl_entry`.`location` =  `tbl_origin_dest`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN tbl_origin_dest destination ON  `tbl_entry`.`dest` = destination.`id` 
LEFT JOIN tbl_project ON  `tbl_entry`.`project_id` =  `tbl_project`.`project_id` 
LEFT JOIN tbl_component ON  `tbl_entry_item`.`component_id` =  `tbl_component`.`component_id` 
LEFT JOIN tbl_status ds ON  `tbl_entry_item`.`dmg_type` = ds.`status_id` 
LEFT JOIN tbl_status fs ON  `tbl_entry_item`.`fix_status` = fs.`status_id` 
LEFT JOIN tbl_equip tbl_eq ON  `tbl_entry`.`equip_id` =  `tbl_eq`.`equip_id` 
WHERE (
tbl_entry.`entry_status_id` !=1
OR tbl_entry.`entry_status_id` IS NULL
)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is your phpmyadmin running on the same server as the PHP code you're failing to execute?

Comment: Yes. The php code works for a certain dataset but when I include everything it stops working on php and still works on phpmyadmin